# Youtube API update default thumbnail from available thumbnails by URL

Tags: youtube, youtube-data-api, video-thumbnails

I want to change default thumbnail of video from 3 Youtube available thumbnails. But seems there's no case like this.

My case: I uploaded video to Youtube successfully. Then it returns 3 thumbnails for this video, such as:

- https://i.ytimg.com/vi/video-id/1.jpg
- https://i.ytimg.com/vi/video-id/2.jpg
- https://i.ytimg.com/vi/video-id/3.jpg

By default, Youtube always choose 1.jpg as default thumbnail, but I want to set 2 or 3 as default. Researched many queries but seems not found.

In this link - https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/thumbnails/set -
 we can create Object thumbnail & set default thumbnail by URL

But in this link -
 https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/update#parameters - Youtube said that seems we can only update some parts via update command, certainly this guide does not list thumbnail as editable part.

Please help me this issue, I don't want to use method upload custom thumbnail, because we'll need to download thumbnail 2 or 3 to server then reupload.

Many thanks

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this? I'm hoping to do the same thing.

Comment: still no, so I'm using reupload method